# Cannot declare class x, because the name is already in use

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i was trying to add a new column to my existing table admission_quota ,using the command :

```
php artisan make:migration add_application_portal_to_admission_quota_table --table=admission_quota
```

but, it returns an error:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class AddReconcilateDateToTransactionTable, because the name is already in use.

what to do now ?

Comment: Did you hit the command before? delete `add_application_portal_to_admission_quota_table` from `database/migrations` directory

Comment: @sta no this is the first time

Comment: check the migrations or seed directory, or change your migration table name

Answer (score 1):

The name of the migration file should be similar to the Class name.

For example,
`AddReconcilateDateToTransactionTable` should be in file named
`anyprefix_add_reconcilate_date_to_transaction_table.php`